# how to call method of other module?

Tags: codeigniter, module

I am new in the CodeIgniter framework and PHP. I am trying to call a method which is in another module's controller. For that I am using:

```
modules::run('addons/demo');
```

but it does not work. How can I accomplish this task?

Comment: Are you using the HMVC modular extension? The docs here will help https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/wiki/Home

Answer (score 0):

include it and it will work but it is a bad practice to use this. Instead create a library and define the method there and it will be accessible in the whole application where ever you load the library. in the application/library create my_library.php

```
<?php Class My_library{
       function common_method(){
            echo 'this is a common method';
       }
   }
```

And call it in the controller method

```
<?php Class test_controller extends CI_Controller{
       function __construct(){
          parent::__construct();
       }

       function index(){
            $this->load->library('my_library');
            $this->my_library->common_method();
       }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

First just need to load the module

```
$this->load->module("module_name");
```

Then call the controller method from the loaded module.

```
$this->module_name->method_name();
```